# Getting Metadata / Schema information from Microsoft Analysis Services

Tags: sql-server, schema, metadata, ssas, cubes

I know you can get metadata and schema info from relational stores in Microsoft SQL Server 2005+ via:

- [INFORMATION_SCHEMA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186778.aspx)
- [Object Catalog Views](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189783.aspx)

What is the equivalent of this in Microsoft Analysis Services?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an XLMA [Discover query](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186653.aspx) to retrieve schema information about a cube.  Also, the AMO ([Analysis Management Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms124924.aspx)) API has an object model that allows you to query cube metadata through a .Net client.  Behind the scenes it sends XMLA commands to the OLAP server.